# installed pdo_mysql but could not find driver while connecting

Tags: php, pdo

Connecting to MySQL Database through PDO is showing **could not find driver** but output of **php -i | grep PDO** is:

```
PDO
PDO supported => enabled
PDO drivers   => mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
```

and ouput of **php -m** contains :

```
PDO
pdo_mysql
```

Comment: Does your script which shows "could not find driver" also run with the shell version of PHP or through a server? The second option might use another ini file

Comment: Nico's probably right. Could be worthwhile to try `service php-fpm(7.x)? restart` or `service apache2 restart`.

Comment: @NicoHaase, Thank You for your help, it worked as shell and server were using different ini file and sorry for replying late.

Comment: @CameronHurd, Thanks mate for your help and sorry for replying late.